# right notation in batchscript while using powershell command

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I dont know, what is wrong, but it outputs only "powershell" :D
I think i did something wrong with the " and ' notations...
Tried some combinations, but it won´t work.

```
for /f %%a in ("powershell -c [math]::Round((Get-ChildItem 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\' -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction Stop).Sum / 1MB)") do set "test=%%~a"
echo %test%
```

output:

```
powershell
```

Comment: `powershell -Command "& {[math]::Round((Get-ChildItem 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam' -File -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction Stop).Sum / 1MB)}"`

Comment: can you explain me the way with & and {}? :)

Comment: cause if i use your code in () without " or ' the script dont work, but with " it cant find powershell

Comment: Your main problem is that you are using a `For /F` command, but not using it with the correct syntax for a parenthesised command. Please open a Command Prompt, type `for /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the output to learn how the command works.

Comment: is there a reason NOT to use powershell for this? the BAT/CMD syntax is ... violently non-intuitive. [*grin*]

Comment: I never tried sticking PowerShell in a batch FOR statement before, but I'm noticing you are using the apostrophe in your command.  If I were to try that, I would use FOR's usebackq option to dodge potential problems.

Comment: i tried now the code while using " ` " inside of (). This will work for me. I tried it with this earlier but not with usebackq delims. so here the complete code: for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`powershell -Command "& {[math]::Round((Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam' -Force | Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction Stop).Sum / 1MB)}"`) do set "test=%%~a"

Comment: @Lee_Dailey i know and its not the first time, that i wish the bat-syntax to hell :D

Comment: As an side note, both the current answers are returning a value in MiB not MB.

Comment: As an aside, @Theo: There's no reason to use `"& { ... }"` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `"..."` directly. Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.

Comment: @mklement0 Ah, goes to show it has been a LOOOOOOONG time since I ever user PowerShell from bat/cmd.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example to assist you:

```sh
@For /F %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
 -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command
 "[Math]::Round( ( ( Get-ChildItem 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam' -Recurse | "^
 "Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction Stop ).Sum / 1MB ), 2 )"
 ') Do @Set "test=%%G"
@Set test 2>NUL
```

*Please note, that as you ware using Round, I specifically asked for it to two decimal places.*

If you do not need to round, but just need two decimal places, then you could change it to this:

```sh
@For /F %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
 -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command
 "\"{0:N2}\" -F ( ( Get-ChildItem 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam' -Recurse | "^
 "Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction Stop ).Sum / 1MB )"
 ') Do @Set "test=%%G"
@Set test 2>NUL
```

Comment: the string format operator and that `{0:n2}` pattern _does_ round to two decimal places. [*grin*] i dunno if it uses the same rounding method, tho.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, you know I meant using `[math]::Round`; the purpose of the comment in my answer was simply because the OP was using `[math]::Round`, but not specifying a number of decimal places.

Comment: i seem to have read it differently. [*grin*] _to me_, this >>> `If you do not need to round, but just need two decimal places, then you could change it to this:` seems to say that the 2nd code block is not doing any rounding ... just truncating to 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

In addition of Compo's Answer, you can do something like this in batch using Powershell :

```
@echo off
Title Get Folder Size MB
Set Folder=C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\
Call :Get_Size "%Folder%"
echo "%Folder%" ==^> Size=%Size%
Pause & Exit /B
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Get_Size <Folder> <Size>
set psCommand=Powershell -C "((Get-ChildItem ""%~1"" -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction Stop).Sum / 1MB).ToString('N2')"
@for /f "delims=" %%S in ('%psCommand%') do set Size=%%S MB
Exit /B
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```